# What does it mean if we disable K-rule in Agda?

Tags: proof-assistants, agda

TL;DR: Can I say, "K-rule in Agda enables people to match $ \forall a.a \equiv a $ with $ \mathit{refl} $"?

In https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.4.1/language/without-k.html#without-k, K-rule is introduced as an implicit rule and it's defaultly enabled. If I understand it correctly, it means parameter of type $ \forall a.a \equiv a $ can be matched with $ \mathit{refl} $. If we disable K-rule, what will happen? What kind of codes is it going to prevent me writing? Because we can always construct $ \forall a . a \equiv a $, even without K, we can always get an instance of $ T $ by passing $ \mathit{refl} $ to any functions with type $ \forall a.a \equiv a \rightarrow T $.

Agda's doc has given me an example which indeed shows a circumstance that can only work with K:

```
K : {A : Set} {x : A} (P : x ≡ x → Set) →
    P refl → (x≡x : x ≡ x) → P x≡x
K P p refl = p
```

In this code, if we can pattern match `x≡x` with `refl`, `P refl` can be trivially equivalent to `P x≡x` (but without K, we can't).

So does that mean: "K enables people to match $ \forall a.a \equiv a $ with $ \mathit{refl} $"? I didn't find the answer on the Agda doc.

If we disable K, will the semantic of Agda's equality type (CH-ISO) change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Axiom K is related to "Uniqueness of Identity Proofs", which says is that any two proofs of equality are themselves equal to each other (i.e. are both Refl). Agda doesn't include K as an axiom, but it (and UIP) can be proved as a theorem using Agda's dependent pattern matching.

Axiom K is inconsistent with homotopy type theory, where the univalence axiom provides ways of constructing equalities other than `refl`. For example, if there are two functions that are pointwise equal, univalence asserts that there is an equality term equating them, but it cannot be `refl` if the functions have different implementations.

All removing K from Agda does is add restrictions to pattern matching, making fewer matches typecheck. The runtime semantics are unchanged, and no new programs typecheck.

For some excellent introductions on the subject, I recommend:

[Pattern Matching without K](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2d29/5b9627f29c2199e58a7d7c93767e741426d6.pdf)

[Unifiers as Equivalences](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/80792194.pdf)

Both of these have more detailed versions in JFP if you have access to a subscription.

Comment: But why can $ a \equiv b $ be matched as refl while $ a \equiv a $ cannot? Should the later expression just a specialized version of the previous one?

Comment: @ice1000 You can, and you get a perfectly good logical system when you do that (i.e. vanilla Agda). But that system happens to be inconsistent with the univalence axiom. As for why it's not a specialized version of the previous one, in terms of unification, they're two different operations. The first yields a solution for $a$, namely $a := b$. But the second does not give a solution for $a$, it simply provides a reflexive equation, since $a := a$ will not allow unification to progress. If we allow $a \equiv a$ to be deleted, we can prove $K$.

Comment: Does this mean we can only allow unification to progress if pattern matching is yielding solutions (which means $\forall a. a \equiv a$ can never be unified (pattern matched) with anything)? What does "delete" mean here in the sense of programming? (All these are under the context of Agda without K)

Comment: I am wondering the same thing. What does delete mean? Can unification not progress unless $ \forall a.a \equiv a $ is not present “somewhere”?

Comment: Also, IIUC, does this mean one can derive `K : {A : Set} {x : A} {y : A} (P : x ≡ y → Set) → P refl → (p : x ≡ y) → P p` in Agda withou k?

Comment: For other people who are also confused, Thomas Streicher’s [Investigations into intensional type theory](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/246539233_Investigations_into_intensional_type_theory) should answer a lot of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm studying this myself and I think the only essential distinction between K and J is that:

- The user of K is expected to provide a type `P : x ≡ x → Set` depending on some loop about `x` (a closed path).
- The user of J is expected to provide a type `Q : (y : A) → x ≡ y → Set` depending on a general path that could be either open or closed. Since `Q` isn't allowed to assume that it is closed, J is more restrictive on the user. You can define `P = Q x` but the reverse is not in general possible.

From a homotopic point of view, K is not possible because the structure of `P` is too rigid; the lack of an adjustable endpoint `y : A` prevents `P` from being continuously transported along arbitrary paths.

This is evidenced by the code below:

```
K : {A : Set} {x : A} (P : x ≡ x → Set)
  → P refl → (p : x ≡ x) → P p
K P d p = {- impossible in HoTT/CuTT -}

J' : {A : Set} {x : A} (Q : (y : A) → x ≡ y → Set)
   → Q x refl → (p : x ≡ x) → Q x p
J' Q d p = Cubical.Foundations.Prelude.J Q d p
```

Comment: Yes! That's also how I would say it after many years of studying of HoTT.