# Why cannot match $ Bool \equiv Bool $ with $ refl $ while $1 \equiv 1$ can?

Tags: proof-assistants

This code depends on agda-stdlib:

```
{-# OPTIONS --without-K #-}
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Bool

open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

-- this code doesn't check, cannot match e with refl
why : (e : Bool ≡ Bool) -> ℕ
why refl = zero

but-why : (e : 1 ≡ 1) -> ℕ
but-why refl = zero
```

I know K-rule means I cannot match $ \forall a.a \equiv a $ with $ refl $, but if $a$ is a concrete value, it can (i.e. $1 \equiv 1$ can be matched with $refl$).
But why I cannot match $Bool \equiv Bool$ with $refl$? Why is type and value treated differently in a dependently-typed programming language?

(Maybe related: [What does it mean if we disable K-rule in Agda?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/98339/79971))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, even without K, you can match against `refl`, but at least one of the endpoints must be an "unconstrained" variable. Both of these type check in Agda-sans-K:

```
foo : ∀ { A B : Set } -> A ≡ B → A → B
foo refl a = a

fooℕ : ∀ { A : Set } -> A ≡ ℕ → A → A
fooℕ refl a = a + 3
```

These cases are (probably) handled by a few standard induction principles for equality (AKA dependent elimination principles), such as "path induction" and "based path induction", which do not rely on axiom K, but are a fundamental ingredient in the definition of the equality type.

Instead, the following does not type check, since the two endpoints are constrained to be the same.

```
bar : ∀ { A : Set } -> A ≡ A → A → A
bar refl a = a
```

I'm unsure about why this does not work as expected. By comparison, in Coq this works fine:

```
Definition bar: forall A : Type, A = A -> A -> A :=
   fun A p x =>
   match p with
   | eq_refl => x
   end .
```

As the translation of the OP's code:

```
Definition foo: (bool = bool) -> nat :=
   fun p =>
   match p with
   | eq_refl => 0
   end .
```

In these two last cases, we do not even need dependent elimination, the regular non-dependent one suffices.

I guess that Agda, when no endpoint is "free", internally translates the match into some form which relies on axiom K, even if in some cases (like the above) there is no real need to do so.

One can indeed define the original `why` pattern match, by generalizing it so that at least one endpoint is "free".

```
why-generalized : {A : Set} -> (e : Bool ≡ A) -> ℕ
why-generalized {.Bool} refl = zero

why : (Bool ≡ Bool) -> ℕ
why = why-generalized
```

(Well, in this case we could also use `why x = zero`, but the point of the above code is to pattern match against `refl`)

Comment: Perhaps the these particular functions don't actually depend on the argument is a factor in the behavior.

Comment: @DerekElkins It's a possibility. I'm rather puzzled by Agda's behaviour here.

Comment: Agda doesn't bother trying to figure out if there is an equivalent non-K matching definition when your declared type is `A = A`. The type signature is primary. The reason The `1 = 1` example works indeed because it considers K to still hold for `ℕ` (you can write it with `--without-K` enabled).

Comment: I don't know why Coq would accept this definition, but it's definitely not possible to implement `bar` in basic Martin-Löf type theory with just the J eliminator for the identity type, which is (roughly) the guideline I used for implementing --without-K (see my thesis for more details). If Coq goes beyond that, then that's some peculiarity of the Coq theory. I think the main use case for --without-K is when you care particularly about compatibility with (extensions of) basic MLTT, so I would be hesitant to add some feature that goes beyond it just because Coq does the same.

Comment: (cross-posted from https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/3265)

Comment: @Jesper Thank you for the link. Why do you state it's not possible with only J? I'm puzzled by that. All we need is non-dependent elimination (aka a recursor) which is weaker than J. I mean, `why-generalized` above type checks, and one can use that to implement `why`. So, it seems definitely possible to do it -- indeed, Coq does that by using a non-dependent `match`, which is roughly equivalent to using J on a constant type family (always $\mathbb N$) (or more precisely based path induction, in HoTT terminology). I thought (based) path induction is feasible in MLTT / HoTT without univalence.

Comment: @Jesper I'm starting to think I'm missing the point here, since both you and Derek Elkins think otherwise. Or perhaps I'm more familiar with Coq compared to Agda, and that's misleading me somehow.

Comment: Indeed, `bar` doesn't require the full power of `K` but rather just a non-dependent version of it. It would be easy to add such a non-dependent K and I believe this would not break any compatibility with HoTT axioms. It seems that Coq has such a non-dependent K. OTOH, it is not possible to implement `bar` in terms of `J`/based path induction (just try it in Agda or Coq if you don't see why), so this is indeed a -- albeit very mild -- extension to the core theory, which needs to be checked for compatibility with any axioms you're using.

Comment: @Jesper I'm sorry to insist but, as I wrote above, `bar` does type check in Coq! Underneath, Coq generalizes that to (essentially) `bar-general : forall A B, A = B -> A -> B`, i.e. transporting over the identity family / `idtoequiv`. Isn't J enough to obtain that? After that, `bar A p x = bar-general A A p x` recovers the wanted term.

Comment: I see, so Coq's match does the generalization for you. `bar-general` can indeed be implemented using only J. Agda doesn't do this generalization and thus rejects the definition. So the question is whether we'd want to add such a step to Agda's unification algorithm. One potential problem is that it could become very hard to *prove* anything about the behavior of a function defined in such a way. But I'll have to think about it some more.

Comment: @Jesper I can now agree. Summing up, the point is not "J can not implement that" (which puzzled me) but "should we really use a kind-of heuristic to automagically translate such cases in a form that J can process?". It's not a matter of the type theory, but a matter of (roughly) syntactic sugar on top of that, and whether that is "good" to humans. To conclude, let me add that I personally find Coq a bit too smart in his dependent matches: I often rewrite working `match x with` code as `match x as .. in .. return .. with` so to avoid relying on Coq's heuristics and use J explicitly.

Comment: Isn't `bar-general` equal to `coerce` (or, `subst`) in Agda? I think they're accepted

Comment: @ice1000 Yes, I think it's `subst`.

Comment: I meant the following: Agda rejects the definition of `bar` because it doesn't automatically generalize the type of the equation. However, if you do the generalization manually by defining `bar` in terms of `bar-general` then it is accepted by Agda.

Answer (score 7):

From the perspective of Homotopy Type Theory (HoTT), i.e. if we have the Univalence Axiom, there are definitely values of `Bool ≡ Bool` that are distinct from `refl`. Because Agda without Axiom K is compatible with univalence, it can't then assume that `refl` is the only value of type `Bool ≡ Bool`.

ℕ, on the other hand, is an h-set in HoTT (see [Section 2.13 of the HoTT book](https://hott.github.io/book/nightly/hott-online-1184-g57d1f98.pdf#page=107)). This is to say that Axiom K restricted to ℕ does hold. This is related to the fact that ℕ is inductively defined (with no parameters or indices) while `Set` is not.

I don't know the exact logic Agda uses. Presumably, it is something like it knows that nullary constructors of an inductive type are identified with themselves in only one way (which wouldn't be true for higher inductive types), and it knows `suc` is injective.

Comment: I have to disagree with this. Coq (which does not assume axiom K) accepts the (translation of) code above just fine. Indeed, even with univalence, the induction principle of equality (AKA dependent elimination) still holds, and in order to define a function $f: a=b \to T$ it is enough to consider only the case where $b$ is $a$ and the argument of $f$ is reflexivity. The induction principle ensures that such a definition is automatically "extended" to all other inhabitants of $a=b$. So, the reason why Agda doesn't like this must be more subtle.

Comment: Still digging into what you said. I'll decide on accepting the answer after I know what is h-set and finish reading the "without K" paper. Sorry for a temporary unaccepting.